# SyntaxError loading html page that has modernizr javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modernizr

I came across [this page](http://jsfiddle.net/dsbonev/cCCZ2/) which uses **[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)** library.I couldn't make out how this works.In jsfiddle page ,it works with no trouble..I  put all that code into a [test.js](http://pastebin.com/HCN0Y6XX) file and added it inside `<head> element` using `<script type="text/javascript"  src="test.js" ></script>` ..

I couldn't figure out how this javascript can be loaded when the html page loads.When I load the [html page](http://pastebin.com/zDr9PRp7),I get an error in `firebug` in `chrome version 18.0.1025.162` that `line55` has `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

I am using `jquery` 's `$(document).ready()` method to initialize most of my other javascript functions..But I am at a loss as to how I can use the above code with jquery..

Can some javascript experts help?

Comment: I copied the whole code from the jsfiddle page..if it works there ,then I guess it should work on my local html page ,I guess:)

Comment: Did you include jquery BEFORE the other script tag?

Comment: i did.. does that cause a conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an illegal character on line 55 which is probably an artefact of copying and pasting from jsfiddle. It's not visible in my IDE but if you click the link to your test.js which appears in the console along with the error, you should see the character highlighted. I deleted everything between the final semi-colon in test.js and the end of the document to get rid of the error.

Comment: Dev tools and firebug are your friend. Chrome's dev tools took me straight to the error and highlighted it.